# Combine IIFEs in grunt/uglify

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

Is there a way in uglify (or another node package if needed) to combine all of my IIFE into a single IIFE?  In my project, we write each file inside of an IIFE and pass the single global into the IIFE as a parameter.

Using the most condensed JS, an IIFE with a "use strict" directive is `31 bytes` (`a` is our single global.)

```
(function(a){"use strict";/* code here */}());
```

That means if we have 20 source files, we end up with 600 bytes of wasted space.  If we have 100 source files, it's 3100 bytes wasted... etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way in uglify (or another node package if needed) to
>   combine all of my IIFE into a single IIFE?

Yes, but with limitations. You could use [`grunt-contrib-uglify`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) which comes with two possibilites:

- Using `wrap`
- Using `banner` and `footer` *(gives you slightly more control of the output)*

Configuration in your `Gruntfile.js` would be:

**`wrap`**

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        wrap: 'foo',
    },
    files: {
       'path/to/output.min.js': ['path/to/input/*.js']
    }
}
```

The value of `wrap` would be your `export` or `global` variable you want to pass. This should work with multiple IFEE's as your global variable will just be passed to the other IFEE's.

**`banner` and `footer`**

```
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: '(function (a) {',
        footer: '})(foo);'
    },
    files: {
       'path/to/output.min.js': ['path/to/input/*.js']
    }
}
```

Your output will be wrapped within `(function (a) { /* your other scripts */ })(foo);`. Downside is, at least for my understanding, that you can't write your code in an IIFE as the IIFE will be generated in your output.

---

Read more in the official [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).